# Couldn't find Beat without an ID ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a marketplace app where uses can post music beats they want to sell and people can buy them.

When a user likes a beat and they want to add the beat to a cart. It's getting stuck on this the create action "@beat = Beat.find(params[:id])"

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

 def create
    @beat = Beat.find(params[:id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_beat(beat)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Item added to cart' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my line_item model

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :beat
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

Here is my cart model

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

    def add_beat(beat)
        current_item = line_items.find_by(beat_id: beat.id)

        if current_item
            current_item.increment(:quantity)
        else
            current_item = line_items.build(beat_id: beat.id)
        end
        current_item
    end

end
```

And last but not least here is my beat model

```
class Beat < ApplicationRecord
    before_destroy :not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_one_attached :mp3
    has_one_attached :image
    has_many :line_items

    private

    def not_referenced_by_any_line_item
        unless line_items.empty?
            errors.add(:base, "line items present")
            throw :abort
        end
    end
end
```

Here are the routes now

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  root 'pages#index'
  get 'users/show'
  resources :beats
  resources :songs
  resources :users
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }

end
```

Comment: What is the error in the 'rails console'?, Did you tried to print `params` and check the 'id' key and if there is a record against that ID for beats table?

Comment: Also, can you show the relevant routes?

Comment: @moritz I have updated my routes

Comment: So the create action should be called on `POST /line_items`. There should be a form that triggers this and it has to include a parameter `id` for the `Beat`. Does it do that?

Comment: @moritz a form inside the views?

Comment: Yes, the user action (button, form submit or link click) that triggers the create action probably doesn't send the id. Then the action tries to find a Beat with nil which fails.